# Why don't parentheses matter in this case of multipication

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Very basic question but can't seem to wrap my head around why this happens.

Normally parentheses indicate that the operation inside must be carried out first.

In this case:

(a * a * a)*(a * a * a * a) = a^7

how does it become a * a * a * a * a * a * a and not (a^3)*(a^4)

I'm looking for an explanation that breaks down the operation into the same way basic exponents and multiplication are explained.

For example 3*3 is explained as 3 cookies being added 3 times.
3*3 = 3+3+3 or 3^2 = 3*3 = 3+3+3

Comment: Are you familiar with the associative law?

Comment: Incidentally, you might first ask yourself what "$a\cdot a\cdot a$" even means.  You know that $a\cdot a$ means adding together $a$ copies of $a$, but what does it mean to multiply _three_ numbers together?

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication is proven to be *associative*; that means you can calculate any part of a series of it first (= setting and removing parenthesis wherever you want), and the result is *always the same*.

All the different variants you noted are correct, and they are all identical.

Answer (score 1):

For this special case, it follows from the commutative property of addition, $ a^7 = a^{3 + 4} = a^{4 + 3} $.

In general, multiplication is an **associative operation** meaning that $ a(bc) = (ab)c$, i.e. you can evaluate in any arbitrary order without affecting the end result.

Answer (score 0):

There's an implied exponent of 1 on $a$. That is, $a = a^1$

If you multiply $a * a$, you get $a^1 * a^1 = a^{1+1} = a^2$. When you multiply two powers of the same number, you add their exponents.

So when you multiply $(a*a*a)*(a*a*a*a)$, you're really doing $$(a^1 *a^1 *a^1) * (a^1 * a^1 * a^1 * a^1) = (a^{1+1+1})*(a^{1+1+1+1}) = a^3 *a^4 = a^{3+4} = a^7$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way of thinking about it:

When you have yet to do any multiplying upon what in the future will be a product, you have the proverbial "empty product," which is always $1\quad$. (When you are at that point, your accumulated exponent is $0\quad$.)

When you have yet to do any adding upon what in the future will be a sum, you have the proverbial "empty sum," which is always $0\quad$.